# Selecting multiple columns conditionally in Oracle10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with something like a dozen different columns. Is there a way to conditionally select columns based on a certain condition?

For example we'll say this a user table with username, password, all that stuff, and a field that holds a count of how many times that user has failed a login. (Wrong password, right username). So instead of having a query that returns nothing when either username or password are wrong, or a query that returns everything when just the username is correct, I would like a query that returns a subset when the username is correct but the password is wrong.

Pseudo SQL:

```
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3,
       column4,
       column5,
       column6,
   --If this condition is not met the following columns are not selected
   IF password = password  
   (
       conditional_column1,
       conditional_column2,
       conditional_column3
   )
FROM source_table
WHERE username = username
```

I have tried a CASE statement and DECODE but each of those only returns one value for each condition. I want to select several columns for a single condition.

I do not have access to PL/SQL and I am trying to keep this all in one query. Anyone know if this is possible?

**EDIT**:

Just to clarify, in my case I do not want to check if I'm asking for username, I want to check if there are any rows where `username = x`. If all I had to do was pass `username` to a function and build a query string this wouldn't be a problem.

So the flow goes:
Get some columns where username is 'x' then, if password is 'y' get these other columns.

Comment: What is the issue with returning additional columns and then in the application layer choosing which to display? Adding columns to an existing result set makes no difference in the explain plan.

Comment: In my particular case I could change one query or five different code files. I know this isn't the ideal solution but it does keep me from refactoring nearly a half-dozen files and crossing my fingers hoping it won't affect something else. This is an inherited project, and I'm truly not being dramatic about the number of files I'd have to change.

Comment: You say you do not have access to PL/SQL, but do you mean creating stored procedures? If you can pass this select statement as a string to the DB, then you should be able to pass an anonymous block with dynamic SQL to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a look at the virtual private database (VPD) feature of oracle

Comment: At first I thought what are you talking about, but this could do it if his issue is really user control.

Comment: This actually looks like it would do the trick. The "column hiding" feature might but just what I need. Don't know if I have permissions for VPD or if I can get the database guys to set it up.

Comment: It's Enterprise Edition, so hopefully you're already paying for it.  And I think it, too, uses PL/SQL, though hopefully not the kind you're not allowed to use.

Answer (score 2):

Justin is right that there is no way (other than SELECT * or derivatives like PIVOT) to get back a variable number of columns from a static query.  My 2 suggestions are:

1. Dynamic SQL, if you have control over how the query gets created.
2. Determine a maximum number of columns, and throw a view over your source_table using CASE/DECODE like you have tried.  You can add an indicator column for each conditional column if a null check is not enough.  I have used this to get around the "can't query unknown domain problem" successfully.

Answer (score 0):

When a query is submitted to the SQL engine, the number of columns that will be selected has to be known.  The SQL engine cannot let the number of columns vary at runtime.

You could, however, use dynamic SQL to assemble the query that would be submitted to the SQL engine dynamically.  For example, I can create a PL/SQL procedure that will dynamically assemble a SQL statement that includes different columns and return a `SYS_REFCURSOR` to the caller.  You can do something similar in whatever language your application is using.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure dyn_emp( p_include_empno in boolean,
  2                                       p_rc           out sys_refcursor )
  3  as
  4    l_sql varchar2(1000);
  5  begin
  6    l_sql := 'SELECT ename ';
  7    if( p_include_empno )
  8    then
  9      l_sql := l_sql || ', empno ';
 10    end if;
 11    l_sql := l_sql || ' from emp';
 12    open p_rc for l_sql;
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL> variable rc refcursor;
SQL> exec dyn_emp( true, :rc );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

ENAME           EMPNO
---------- ----------
SMITH            7369
ALLEN            7499
WARD             7521
JONES            7566
MARTIN           7654
BLAKE            7698
CLARK            7782
SCOTT            7788
KING             7839
TURNER           7844
ADAMS            7876
JAMES            7900
FORD             7902
MILLER           7934

14 rows selected.

SQL> exec dyn_emp( false, :rc );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

ENAME
----------
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD
JONES
MARTIN
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
TURNER
ADAMS
JAMES
FORD
MILLER

14 rows selected.
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but it's not going to work. As I've mentioned I don't have PL/SQL access and doing it in another language would create extra queries. The condition checks I need are dependent on the info in the database, username or password exist in database. I'd have to do at least one extra database call to check for username.